# Nonsensical require errors in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to require a downmark script called, appropriately enough, `downmarkit`.

Four lines into the beginning of my code is the block:
`require_relative 'downmarkit'`

The file does exist:

```
$ls /home/mike/public_html/downmarkit
/home/mike/public_html/downmarkit
```

Yet when I execute my script from the public_html folder...

```
$ruby _import.rb
_import.rb:4:in `require_relative': no such file to load -- /home/mike/public_html/downmarkit (LoadError)
```

This is probably a really silly mistake on my part, but I'm not seeing it. Why can't ruby see what is right in front of it's face?

Comment: Is the file read protected? The web server runs as a separate user, so try a "chmod o+r downmarkit".

Comment: Tried both of those. Actually, the only reason I'm using require_relative is because the standard ./ wouldn't work either.

The permissions change didn't work.. same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When requiring ruby looks for file with `.rb` extension. Your `ls` says that this file has no extension.